# Where can I download Windows 8 Release Preview?

Tags: download, windows-8-preview, iso-image

I have check the page http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/release-preview.
But it redirect to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/meet with no link to the free preview version.

Where can I get the .ISO format of the Release Preview?

(Maybe the Release Preview is restrict to U.S. only ?)

Comment: It's sad that this is no longer available as to my experience Consumer Preview and Release Preview were one of if not the best Windows versions that have ever existed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the Windows 8 Release Preview page no longer exists, the *actual* download links on Microsoft's servers are still active - notice the download link domain: `http://go.microsoft.com`:

> ### **32-bit (x86)**
>
> **Download link:** http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251533 (2.5 GB)
>
> Sha 1 hash — 0x8BED436F0959E7120A44BF7C29FF0AA962BDEFC9
>
> ### **64-bit (x64)**
>
> **Download link:** http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=251532 (3.3 GB)
>
> Sha 1 hash — 0xD76AD96773615E8C504F63564AF749469CFCCD57

[Alternative official download links](http://www.forumswindows8.com/windows-8-download/) from Microsoft's servers: `http://iso.esd.microsoft.com`:

> ### **32-bit (x86)**
>
> **Download link:** http://iso.esd.microsoft.com/WRPDL/D29D6C5B1D8AF956B5DA9DF738CFD92DFD4F6C8FB/Windows8-ReleasePreview-32bit-English.iso (2.5 GB)
>
> Sha 1 hash — 0x8BED436F0959E7120A44BF7C29FF0AA962BDEFC9
>
> ### **64-bit (x64)**
>
> **Download link:** http://iso.esd.microsoft.com/WRPDL/D29D6C5B1D8AF956B5DA9DF738CFD92DFD4F6C8FB/Windows8-ReleasePreview-64bit-English.iso (3.3 GB)
>
> Sha 1 hash — 0xD76AD96773615E8C504F63564AF749469CFCCD57

Comment: Seems the [only](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6658553#6658553) legal option is to trial as keys don't work, dunno if that works on Preview, though...

Comment: It's obvious that you can't get keys anymore, but maybe an official download link can still be useful.

Comment: I'm downloading this version. I'll confirm if it's still usable.

Comment: It worked. I used the key mention on Tom's Hardware website (see Tom Wijsman answer)

Answer (score 5):

Release preview is no longer available from Microsoft because Windows 8 is now fully released. Any attempts will just refer you to the main Windows 8 page where you can purchase the full license.

Answer (score 2):

Tom's Hardware Guide hosts [mirrors](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Windows-8-Preview-Release-Download-Latest-Win-8-RP,15839.html) for these near the bottom of the article, including keys, whether it's legal to obtain them from there is doubtful. I'd advise you to not go down the Preview route at this time though because it will run out in January anyway. You could just as well install a RTM version *without a key* and use it for the 30 days up to somewhere in December, which you can extend up to 120 days by rearming. But then again, it's up to you whether how legal you stay with the EULA...

> [**Jared Tritsch:** I couldn't activate a RO license yesterday on a lab machine](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6658553#6658553).

It appears it might even not be possible to use the preview, so you'd have to use a trial period.

Comment: "You could just as well install a RTM version without a key and use it for the 30 days up to somewhere in December, which you can extend up to 120 days by rearming." - Are you sure? RTM Std/Pro *requires* key entry during setup AFAIK, and there is no grace period any longer in Win8.

Comment: @Karan: Oh, did they change that? Doesn't sound good...

Comment: I think it's because the same source image contains the bits for Std and Pro, and which version gets installed depends entirely on the key entered. So it needs to be specified during setup itself.